# Oracle / PHP / Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, oracle, httpd, rhel4

I have built a web app that was performing very fast, until users from a third coutry (the majority) started using the application. Now its very slow.

I see from the logs that I keep getting ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred when the usage is at the peak. How can I solve this?

Then what setup of apache would help speed up stuff? Load balancing, multiple instances?

Am running it on RHEL4

Answer (score 2):

"Connect timeout". A web app should generally have a connection pool permanently connected to the database. Setting up a database connection (and killing it at the end) is pretty expensive so it is not something you should be doing for each user.

Suggest you look at [Database Resident Connection Pooling](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28395/oci09adv.htm#LNOCI9110) in 11g

Comment: the database is on a different machine, so the connection pooling you are talking abuot is to be implemented there or at the client?

Comment: There are changes at both the database and client end. Details in a white paper
http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/php/pdf/php-scalability-ha-twp.pdf
and you would probably get more detailed help at Oracle's PHP forum
http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=178&start=0

Comment: +1 for both question and answer.